# The second time this code is run, "cd" gives "Cannot find path" error

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I'm new to C.
I was running my code in VSC and somehow when I run the code the first time, it works normally but when I rerun the code, it has an error:

> cd : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\phuon\OneDrive\Tai liêu\C C++.vscode' because it does not exist.

At line:1 char:1

- cd "c:\Users\phuon\OneDrive\Tai liêu\C C++.vscode" ; if ($?) { gcc  ...

  - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\phuon...\C C++.vscode:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int findEvenNumber(int y)
{
    return y % 2;
}

int main()
{
    int number;
    printf("Type the number you want to find: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    int even = findEvenNumber(number);
    if (even == 0)
    {
        printf("This is an even number");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("This is not an even number");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How could it work the first time, but not the second time?

Anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: there is no 'cd' in the posted code

Comment: @user3629249 can you specify?

Comment: Why are you compiling to your one drive? Try compiling to a folder that is not being synced/used by another program.

Comment: The C code you showed us is perfectly valid (though there are some suggestions I could make to improve it). Your problem has nothing to do with your C program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Visual Studio code (VSCode) is an IDE, not a compiler:

   - You need to install VSCode
   - Then you need to install a compiler (e.g. GCC)
   - Finally, you need to install and configure a plugin (Visual Studio Code "extensions") so that VSCode can use the compiler.
2. I suspect something is wrong with the "configuration".
3. SUGGESTION:

   - Create a new project, in a new folder.
   - Do *NOT* create your project in a OneDrive folder.
   - Create a small, "hello world" C++ program in your new project.
   - See if you can reproduce the problem in the new location.
4. Please tell us:

   - Your compiler and version (e.g. C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe v10.3.0).
   - Your extension and version (e.g. Microsoft C/C++ for Visual Studio Code v1.97).
   - Whether or not you have the same problem with the new project in the new folder.

Comment: Thank you! The issue indeed is from the PATH of the OneDrive folder. After creating a new folder on my desktop, my code runs perfectly despite how many times I rerun it.
This is my compiler and version:
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe v11.2.0
My extension and version: 
Microsoft C/C++ for Visual Studio Code v1.97